# Replicating is.element

Tags: r

I need to replicate the is.element function in R. I have two vectors and need to compare the values in each where if one matches the other the output is True and False for all others.

Code I've tried that does not quite work:

```
x <- c(3, 0, -2, 0)
y <- c(-1, 0, 1)
n <- length(x)
answer <- is.logical(x)
for (i in 1:n) {
  if (x[i] == y[i]) { 
    answer[i] <- TRUE
  } else {
    answer[i] <- FALSE
    }
  }
answer
```

Intended answer:

```
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, I just figured it out. Thanks again.

```
x <- c(3, 0, -2, 0)
y <- c(-1, 0, 1)
n <- length(x)
m <- length(y)
answer <- is.logical(x)
for (i in 1:n) {
  for (j in 1:m) {
    if (x[i] == y[j]) {
    answer[i] <- TRUE
    break
  } else {
    answer[i] <- FALSE
   }
  }   
}
answer
```

Answer (score 0):

An option would be `outer` to do the comparison of each element of 'x' with 'y' to return a logical `matrix`, which can be reduced to a logical `vector` 
by getting the `sum` of TRUE elements in each row (`rowSums`) and check if it is greater than 0

```
rowSums(outer(x, y, `==`)) > 0
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

---

Or create the logical matrix with `sapply` and do a `colSums

```
colSums(sapply(x, `==`, y)) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks, akrun. However, and sorry I didn't state earlier, I am restricted to using 'for loops' and 'if' statements. How do I compare each element from vector x to vector y in this fashion?