# use for loop to mimic is.element in R

Tags: r

Write an R program to mimic the built-in R function is.element(x, y) of two vectors x and y. In other words, your program returns a vector answer of the same length as x, and answer[i] is TRUE if and only if x[i] is an element of y. Do not use any R’s built-in function such as is.element() or %in%.

Here is my code: (but it doesn't return a vector)

```
x <- c(3, 0, -2, 0)
y <- c(-1, 0, 1)
n <- length(x)
answer <- logical(n)
for (i in 1:n){
  if (x[i]) {
    answer <- TRUE
    }
     else {
    answer <- FALSE

  }
 
}
answer
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/58054098/8436923

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `answer[i]` in the loop. Try -

```
x <- c(3, 0, -2, 0)
y <- c(-1, 0, 1)
n <- length(x)
answer <- logical(n)

for (i in 1:n){
 answer[i] <- any(x[i] == y)
}

answer
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

---

If usage of `any` is not allowed you can also use a double loop for every value in `x` and `y`.

```
x <- c(3, 0, -2, 0)
y <- c(-1, 0, 1)
n <- length(x)
answer <- logical(n)
for (i in seq_along(x)){
  tmp <- FALSE
  for(j in seq_along(y)) {
    tmp <- tmp | x[i] == y[j]
  }
  answer[i] <- tmp
}
answer
```